# I'm trying to create an invite tracker using discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Alright, my goal here is to create an invite tracker. Currently, you can run the command `/invites` and it'll tell you how many invites you have. Here's the code for it.

```
@client.command()
async def invites(ctx):
    totalInvites = 0
    for i in await ctx.guild.invites():
        if i.inviter == ctx.author:
            totalInvites += i.uses
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, you've invited {totalInvites} member{'' if totalInvites == 1 else 's'}!")
```

I'm wondering if there's a way I can find others' invites as well by doing `/invites @user`. Also, to go even further, could I possibly create a `/leaderboards` command? It should show an embed with a list of the top 10 people for invites along with how many invites they have. And I'd like it if there was a way to subtract the number of invites when someone leaves the server.

Answer (score 1):

```py
@client.command()
async def invites(ctx, usr: discord.Member=None):
    if usr == None:
       user = ctx.author
    else:
       user = usr
    total_invites = 0
    for i in await ctx.guild.invites():
        if i.inviter == user:
            total_invites += i.uses
    await ctx.send(f"{user.name} has invited {totalInvites} member{'' if totalInvites == 1 else 's'}!")
```

I apologize that I was unable to actually run the code. If the above code produces an error please tell me.

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell what this is for. Is it for the `/invites @user`?

Comment: @iCrySam it is a modified version of your function that will allow you to specify a user. You can run it normally (`/invites`) and it will get all of *your* invites, or you can do `/invites @user` and it will get all invites for that user.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to this stuff, could you explain how the code works? Also, https://hasteb.in/diwudoda.py doesn't seem to work either. I included the error in the link.

Comment: @iCrySam Problem with the code is that when you send the message, you are sending the number of invites with the variable `totalInvites`, which I renamed to `total_invites'. I fixed it here: https://hasteb.in/eyovibix.py. I also added more comments to the other code, here: https://hasteb.in/galoqehe.py

Comment: https://hasteb.in/eyovibix.py sends this error `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'`.